# разбор get запроса

Tags: http, get

Мне нужно написать простейший сервер, который читать get запрос браузера, парсит его, и из get запроса получает адрес html файла, который нужно вывести. Сколько не читала информации, не нашла внятного считывания адреса с запроса get. Подскажите пожалуйста , как это грамотно сделать? 
ex: `localhost:8000/Documents/example.html`
нужно получить отсюда : `/Documents/example.html`, чтобы потом содержимое отправить на сайт. 
Спасибо!

Comment: Так на чём вы это пишите? Кажется во всех ЯП есть библиотеки для разбора урлов

Comment: на питоне. Знаю, что там есть библиотека requests, мне не совсем понятно, как с помощью нее распарсить и получить то, что нужно

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import json

PORT = 8000

class Handler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

        self.wfile.write(json.dumps({"success": True}))

        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        json_string = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        data = json.loads(json_string)
        print (data)

httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print ("serving at port", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Есть такой вариант, открыта для предложений получше)